# Are finite nilpotent groups the only finite groups with abelian Frattini quotient?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

It is obvious that if the Frattini quotient of a finite group $G$ is abelian, then $G$ is abelian by nilpotent and that finite nilpotent groups have abelian Frattini quotient.

I wonder if there is an example of a non-nilpotent finite group with abelian Frattini quotient ?

A better thing would be to have a nice characterization of such finite groups.

Comment: By a theorem of Gaschütz, a finite group is nilpotent when its Frattini quotient is nilpotent. (Satz III.3.5 in Huppert's *Endliche Gruppen I*)

Comment: Indeed, this is well-known, see Theorem B here: https://www.emis.de/proceedings/Chicho2001/Otal.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is well known, but here is a quick proof anyway.

Suppose that $G/\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent, and let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Then $P\Phi(G) \unlhd G$ so, by the Frattini Argument, $G = N_G(P)P\Phi(G)= N_G(P)\Phi(G)$. Hence $G = N_G(P)$ by the non-generator property of $\Phi(G)$. So all Sylow subgroups are normal, and $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: if useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini%27s_argument

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt to entertain those who knew the answer.

> > **Question 1.** Let $G$ be a finitely generated group such that $G/\Phi(G)$ is Abelian. Is $G$ nilpotent?

The answer is yes if we assume moreover that $G$ is linear (e.g., $G$ is finite). But the answer is **no in general**, as the the first Girgorchuk group $G_1$ is such that $[G_1, G_1] \subset \Phi(G_1)$. For more examples, see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16777/generation-in-a-group-versus-generation-in-its-abelianization/246951#246951).

Let $W(G)$ denote the $N$-Frattini subgroup of $G$, that is the intersection of the maximal normal subgroups of $G$ when defined, $G$ otherwise. (See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259490/has-the-jacobson-baer-radical-of-a-group-been-studied/259545#259545) for results related to $W(G)$.) Note that $G/W(G)$ is Abelian for any soluble group $G$.

> > **Question 2.** Let $G$ be a finitely generated group such that $G/W(G)$ is Abelian. Is $G/\Phi(G)$ Abelian?

The answer is **no**, because some Sunic group of intermediate growth is a counter-example, see [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01216.pdf).

> > **Question 3.** Let $G$ be a finite group such that $G/W(G)$ is Abelian. Is $G$ soluble?

The answer is no because of the symetric group $S_n$ with $n \ge 5$. One may try to get a classification though. Possibly useful:

> > **Lemma (Baer).** Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $W(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $W(N) \subset W(G)$.

Comment: Classifying finite groups such that $G/W(G)$ is abelian sounds a bit optimistic. For instance, $H\wr A$ is such a group for every finite group $H$ and any non-trivial finite solvable group $A$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for spotting the $G_1$-typo, it's corrected now. And indeed, "classification" is the wrong word. My intention was just to echo OP's question about the existence of a "nice characterization" of such groups. (By the way, are you assuming $H$ to be simple in your last comment?).

Comment: No I didn't assume $H$ simple. The proof is as follows: in $H\wr A$, the normalizer of $H$ is normal and co-solvable. If $S$ is a simple quotient of $H\wr A$, the image of $H$ also has a normal co-solvable normalizer, hence is equal to $S$. So the image of $H$ is either $\{1\}$ or $S$. But it's the same for another conjugate copy of $H$ (and there's one since $A\neq 1$. Since these pairwise commute, it follows that all have trivial image.

Comment: Thanks for this. My question was derived from Galois theory, hence the groups I was considering were always finite.