Groups killed by centralizing one element
What groups $G$ contains an element $g$ such that $G/(g\text{ is made central})=1$ (or equivalently $[g,G]=G$, where $[g,G]:=\langle[g,h]\colon h\in G\rangle$)?
A necessary condition is that $G$ is a perfect group. A sufficient condition is that $G$ is a nonabelian simple group. However, it seems that neither condition is complete.
I'm happy to assume $G$ is finitely generated and finitely presented (actually, I'm happy to assume $G$ is a $3$-manifold group). Other interesting necessary and sufficient conditions are also welcome.

What does $G/(g\text{ is central})=1$ mean? By $[g,G]=G$ do you mean $G={[g,h]:h\in G}$?

I would guess it would mean $\langle [g,h] : h \in G \rangle$, but this should be clarified.

For a finite group, perfect is enough. But an infinite perfect group can be the union of its proper normal subgroups.

@DaveBenson One example is the subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(\aleph_\omega)$ of all permutations with support strictly less than $\aleph_\omega$. Is there a finitely generated example?

@SeanEberhard That's a good example, and a good question, to which I don't know the answer.

I don't really understand the intended question. But it is a famous open question (e.g., in Baumslag's list) to find a finitely generated perfect group $G$ such that $G$ is not normally generated by any single element. As already mentioned here, it is easy to check that no finite $G$ yields an example.

If $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime, the triangle group $\langle x,y,z\mid x^a=y^b=(xy)^c\rangle$ is killed by making $x$ central.

@YCor What is Baumslag's list?

@SeanEberhard Baumslag-Myasnikov-Shpilrain. Open problems in combinatorial group theory, Second edition. See problem (FP14).

I hope that I am correctly interpreting the intended question.
I will use $x$ instead of $g$ to denote the distinguished element with the property that $[G,x] = G$, assuming there is such an element, and I will assume that $[G,x]$ denotes the subgroup $\langle [g,x]: g \in G \rangle,$ which is the usual group-theoretic interpretation of that notation.
Isn't it then the case that we have $G = [G,x]$ if and only if both $G$ is perfect, and $G$ is generated by the conjugates of $x$?
For if $G$ is generated by the conjugates of $x$, we have $G = \langle x \rangle [G,x],$ since $x^{g} = x(x^{-1}x^{g}) \in x[G,x]$ (and $[G,x]$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ by standard commutator identities).
Hence if $G$ is generated by conjugates of $x$ and $[G,x]$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, then $G$ has a non-trivial cyclic homomorphic image, and is not perfect.
Thus if $G$ is perfect, and is generated by the conjugates of $x$, then $G = [G,x].$
On the other hand, if $G = [G,x],$ then certainly $G = [G,G],$ so $G$ is perfect. Also, $G = \langle x^{-1}x^{g}: g \in G \rangle,$ so certainly $G = \langle x^{g} : g \in G \rangle$, and $G$ is generated by the conjugates of $x$.
In conclusion, a perfect group $G$ satisfies $G = [G,x]$ for some $x \in G$ if and only if $G$ is generated by one of its conjugacy classes.

For reference, this is called a “weight one” group. https://mathoverflow.net/a/54965/1345

It is clear that the weight of a group is no more than the rank. Also, a 2-generator perfect group has weight one (kill one generator, the quotient is cyclic and perfect).

Here is a proof for finite perfect groups. Possibly this is already what Dave Benson had in mind.
Let $G$ be a finite perfect group. If $G \cong G_1 \times G_2$ for nontrivial $G_1$ and $G_2$ then by induction there exists $x_i \in G_i$ such that $G_i = [G_i, x_i]$ and $G = [G_1, x_1][G_2, x_2] = [G, (x_1, x_2)]$, so we may assume $G$ is not a direct product. If $G$ is simple then $G = [G, x]$ for any nontrivial $x \in G$, so we may also assume $G$ is not simple. Let $N \triangleleft G$ be a minimal normal subgroup. Then by induction there is some $xN \in G/N$ such that $G/N = [G/N, xN]$, i.e., $G = MN$ where $M = [G, x]$. We cannot have $M \cap N = 1$ since $G$ is not a direct product, so by minimality of $N$ we must have $M \cap N = N$ and therefore $G = M$.

Actually I was just going to kill the intersection of the maximal normal subgroups. In a perfect finite group, the quotient is a direct product of simple groups, and this is generated by the conjugates of any element that is not the identity in any component.

This viewpoint (for finite groups) reminds me somewhat of a (not directly relevant) Theorem of Gasch"utz :  a finite group $G$ has a faithful complex irreducible character if and only if the socle of $G$ is generated by a single $G$-conjugacy class.
